# How to include vars file in a vars file with ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to include a vars file in Ansible into another vars file dynamically?

I.e. I have  vars file:

```
---
definitions:
- { product: web_v2, suite: mysuite, include: default_step.yml }
- { product: prod2, suite: mysuite2, include: default_step.yml }
```

I want the contents of `default_step.yml` to be added to the dictionary. Note this is in a **vars file** so the documentation on how to include a vars file from a task doesn't seem to apply.

All I can think of is to template this file with jinja and use its `{% include %}` function, and then afterwards use `include_vars` from the main task but that seems complicated...

Comment: Vars files have no built-in include statement.

When you include a vars files with the `include_vars` task the content of the dictionary would be overridden unless you have `hash_behaviour=merge` defined in your Ansible config. Alternatively you can use my action plugin [`include_vars_merged`][1]. Both variants though would only merge the dictionary on the first level. Maybe you can use my plugin as a base and implement deep merging or directly a real `include`.

  [1]: https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838

Answer (score 70):

Unfortunately, vars files do not have include statements.

You can either put all the vars into the `definitions` dictionary, or add the variables as another dictionary in the same file.

If you don't want to have them in the same file, you can include them at the playbook level by adding the vars file at the start of the play:

```
---
- hosts: myhosts

  vars_files:
    - default_step.yml
```

or in a task:

```
---
- hosts: myhosts

  tasks:
    - name: include default step variables
      include_vars: default_step.yml
```

Comment: How would one merge vars files? Such as having a `defaults.yml` and small `overrides.yml`?

Comment: going to have to look up what the `definitions` dictionary is.

Comment: Here is how to do it with `definitions dictionary` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555008/7668448 for example

Comment: if vars in a top level folder , eg /vars/main.yml , will ansible automatically read them, or do I need to use vars_files: /vars/main.yml . note playbooks are in /tasks/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but there's actually a really simple solution to this.

While you cannot include a vars file in a vars file directly, you can absolutely specify the vars file you want to include in a yaml file and then include it. For instance, if you had the yaml vars file named 'profile.yml`:

```
included_roles: ['vars1.yaml', 'vars2.yml`]
```

Then you can simply load that and loop through `included_roles` to import all the vars files you want to include something like so:

```
- name: Include profile variables
  include_vars:
    file: profile.yml

- name: Include role variables
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ included_roles }}"
```

It may not work well in all contexts, especially if the goal is to use additional vars files to logic your way through the original imported vars file, so try and think through the flow of your design.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I had the same issue today, what I did is simple : changing my script that send my playbook from my local host to the server, before sending it with maven command, I did this :

```
cat common_vars.yml > vars.yml
cat snapshot_vars.yml >> vars.yml
# or 
#cat release_vars.yml >> vars.yml
mvn ....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put your servers in the `default_step` group and those vars will apply to it:

```
# inventory file
[default_step]
prod2
web_v2
```

Then just move your `default_step.yml` file to `group_vars/default_step.yml`.

Comment: The question is about how to include multiple vars files, not only one. OP was especially asking how he can include multiple vars files in another vars file (default_step.yml).