# In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, in a role, I have vars files like this:

```
vars/
    app1.yml
    app2.yml
```

Each file contains vars specific to an app/website like this:

```
name: app1
git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
# ...
```

Ideally, without the task knowing in advance which apps have variable files, I'd like to end up with an array called `apps` like this:

```
apps:
  - name: app1
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
    # ...
  - name: app2
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git
    # ...
```

ie, that combines the variables from the files into one.

I know I can load all the variable files like this:

```
- name: Load var files
  with_fileglob:
    - ../vars/*.yml
  include_vars: '{{ item }}'
```

But given each file has identical variable names, it will overwrite each previous set of variables. I can't see a way to load the variables and put them into an `apps` array.

I'm open to rearranging things slightly if it's the only way to make something like this possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can not do that. Variables will always override variables with the same name. The only thing you could do with this exact setup is to [write your own vars plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#vars-plugins) which reads those files and merges them into an array.

If you are open to change the structure of your apps definition you can use a hash and [set your `hash_behavior=merge`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). In each vars file then you'd have a definition like:

```
apps:
  app1:
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
```

---

```
apps:
  app2:
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git
```

When Ansible loads both files it will merge it automatically together into:

```
apps:
  app1:
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
  app2:
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git</pre>
```

But be advised that `hash_behavior=merge` fundamentally changes the default behavior of Ansible on a global level. Make sure all your roles do not have issues with this setting. The documentation mentions:

> We generally recommend not using this setting unless you think you have an absolute need for it

If you still use Ansible 1 you could use one of my old plugins instead: [include_vars_merged](https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838). Basically this adds the behavior of `hash_behavior=merge` to only a single task.

<sub>I have not yet looked into migrating this to Ansible 2 though and currently it looks like I won't have the need for it any longer.</sub>

Comment: In Ansible 2 you can use the [`combine`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) Jinja filter but it does require that you know the hashes you want to combine up front

Comment: I had _so_ much hope in this filter but unfortunately you can not use it to extend a hash and store the result with the same name. `some_hash: "{{ some_hash | combine({foo: bar}) }}"` _This_ would have been useful.

Comment: Thanks both. I feared there was no simple answer - I'll find some other, less nice, way to handle these vars. I'd come across `hash_behaviour=merge` but was wary given it changes Ansible's behaviour so much. Also `combine` raised my hopes too, only to swiftly dash them. So close…

Comment: In case you start from a clean playbook, you could load one set of variables and then load them into your target dictionary from the `hostvars` dictionary, filtering out any keys that start with `ansible_`, `group`, `inventory_`, `module_`, `omit`, and `playbook_`. On the second step, filter out your target dictionary, as well.

Comment: The statement "You can not do that ... The only thing you could do with this exact setup is to write your own vars plugin which reads those files and merges them into an array." is wrong. See my answer. –

Answer (score 9):

Well, you cannot directly build an array, but you can achieve the same effort with a dict.

Suppose you want to construct an array:

```
[{
    name: 'bob',
    age: 30
}, {
    name: 'alice',
    age: 35 
}]
```

You can put each element in a file like:

#### bob.yml

```
bob:
  name: bob
  age: 30
```

#### alice.yml

```
alice:
  name: alice
  age: 35
```

Place these files in the same dir (e.g. `user`), then use `include_vars` to load the whole dir:

```
- name: Include vars
  include_vars:
    name: users
    dir: user
```

This will give you a dict `users`:

```
users:
  alice:
    name: alice
    age: 35
  bob:
    name: bob
    age: 30
```

User the `dict2items` filter in ansible, you get the array you want

Answer (score 6):

Use attribute [name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#parameter-name) and put the included variables into the dictionaries. Fit the *name* of the dictionaries to your needs. For example

```yaml
    - name: Load var files
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "incl_vars_{{ item|basename|splitext|first }}"
      with_fileglob:
        - vars/*.yml
```

Then, use the lookup plugin [varnames](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/varnames.html#varnames-lookup-matching-variable-names) (New in version 2.8.), find all dictionaries, and iterate the list. In the loop use the lookup plugin [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html#vars-lookup-templated-value-of-variables) (New in version 2.5.) and create the list *apps*. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        apps: "{{ apps|default([]) + [lookup('vars', item)] }}"
      loop: "{{ query('varnames', '^incl_vars_(.*)$') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
apps:
  - git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git
    name: app2
  - git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
    name: app1
```

You can convert the list to a dictionary if you want to

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        apps: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(apps)) }}"
      vars:
        _keys: "{{ apps|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
apps:
  app1:
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
    name: app1
  app2:
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git
    name: app2
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir.  I used a slight variation of your solution but I used your idea and framework for the heavy lifting... My data structure in the files was a little different.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Ansible 2.2`, the `include_vars` ([link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html)) module has been expanded quite a bit.

It's now possible to do something like:

```
- include_vars:
    name: 'apps'
    dir: '../vars'
    extensions:
      - 'yaml'
      - 'yml'
```

`name` is the key there. From the module page:

> The name of a variable into which assign the included vars. If omitted (null) they will be made top level vars.

This allows you to convert:

```
vars/
    app1.yml
    app2.yml
    ...
```

app1.yml:

```
name: app1
git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
# ...
```

app2.yml:

```
name: app2
git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git
# ...
```

Into...

```
apps:
  - name: app1
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app1.git
    # ...
  - name: app2
    git_repo: https://github.com/philgyford/app2.git
    # ...
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution you posted? Because Ansible will not accept vars file being a list, it must be a dictionary. It will [throw an error `../vars/app1.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/13dd1acbecef23671c30ef619953edd658e21072/lib/ansible/plugins/action/include_vars.py#L243).

Comment: What if you want to merge two child arrays? Such as a having two `apps` vars merged?

Comment: @techraf - you're correct. The hyphens need removing from the `appX.yml` files so that they're dictionaries. They're unnecessary anyway, as the list is exactly what this method is looking to breakdown in to separate files. I've updated my answer to have a functioning example. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Ansible v2.0 you can do it:

```
- name: merging hash_a and hash_b into hash_c
  set_fact: hash_c="{{ hash_a|combine(hash_b) }}"
```

Check more under Ansible filters - Combining hashes/dictionaries (coming from Jinja2)

Comment: Can you show how to do this with to vars files? Do I have to do it with every single array within the vars file? Can I somehow do it for the entire vars file?

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to post a possible alternate solution by getting a list of variables that match a pattern, then you can just process all those variables, sorta manual merge.

The following code block gives an example of pulling all variables that match a specific pattern and looping.  you could set a new fact with them merged, or simply process them all individually.

```
- name: "debug2"   debug:
    msg: "value is: {{ lookup('vars', item) }} "   
  loop: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | select('match', '^linux_hosts_entries') |list  }}"
```

see the following [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/Ssnk6exNjNs) for further details.

Comment: Please provide the core details of the post in your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change default behavior of hash. I suggest you my solution.
I define multiple variables (with same regex) when Ineed to merge them, I filter them from hostvars. Eg:

```
- name: Combine variables with prefix enabled_services
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].keys() | map('regex_search', 'enabled_services.*') | select('string') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:

```
- name: Load data
  run_once: true
  set_fact:
    my_data: "{{ my_data|default([]) + [lookup('file', item) | from_yaml] }}"
  with_fileglob: "../data/*.yml" # relative to this file
```