# Appending to an ansible task's variables in another role

Tags: ansible

(This is a cross-post from [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/V-0dFWmEWWE), since I haven't gotten any answers there.)

I've recently set up fail2ban for ssh on one of my servers using https://galaxy.ansible.com/tersmitten/fail2ban/ .  This was very easy, and I'm loving galaxy.

Now, I'm wanting to extend fail2ban to also block IPs that have failed basic auth checks in Apache too many times.  Since all my hosts run ssh, but not all run Apache, I've created a new role for this (cleverly named 'apache', while the first is 'common').  However, as shown in the fail2ban role's README, configuration of individual services is done with an array, fail2ban_services, and redefining that in my apache role overwrites what was defined in common (or, due to timing, vice versa).

I've seen that [I can change the hash behavior](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour), which would seem to do what I want.  I'm wary of this, however, since it's a global change.

There is also [the combine filter for jinja](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), but [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555008/120999) indicate I can't do what I want, which would be

```
fail2ban_services: "{{ fail2ban_services | combine({...}) }}"
```

Is there another method to do this combination?  Or perhaps am I going about this the wrong way, and should be architecting this differently?

I'm using ansible 2.0.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

`hash_behavior: merge` and the `combine` filter would not be helpful, because those are for hashes. If I get the docs of fail2ban right, the `fail2ban_services` variable though is a list of hashes:

```
fail2ban_services:
  - name: serviceA
    ...
  - name: serviceB
    ...
  - name: serviceC
    ...
```

You can easily merge lists:

```
listA: "{{ listB + listC }}"
```

... but the same limitations apply as for the combine filter. You can not override a variable which depends on itself, Ansible will complain about some "recursive loop detected" or so. No clue why this is such a big problem for Ansible, there should nothing be recursive in doing `a = a + b`. But unfortunately that's how it is.

If I understood your description, you define the `fail2ban_services` list in your role `common`. Then later you want to re-define it in the role `apache`. How is actually the fail2ban role implemented? Do you have 3 roles then in your playbook like so?

```
roles:
  - common
  - apache
  - fail2ban
```

And the goal is, the first roles define what the last role then is using?

Given the mentioned limitations, my only idea then would be to rename your variables. The role `common` will define `fail2ban_services_common`, the role `apache` will define `fail2ban_services_apache` and then you pass the combined value to `fail2ban`:

```
roles:
  - common
  - apache
  - role: fail2ban
    fail2ban_services: "{{ fail2ban_services_common + fail2ban_services_apache}}"
```

Comment: `common` is a role that depends on the fail2ban role from galaxy (that is, `roles/common/meta/main.yaml` specifies [a dependency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies).  `apache` is another role that *also* depends on the fail2ban role.  I'd like to define ssh-related fail2ban rules in `common`, define apache-related fail2ban rules in `apache`, and have ansible combine the two.  [...]

Comment: Since fail2ban is generic and may be depended on by any number of variable other roles, it can't hard-code a variable number of variable names (also, it's from galaxy, not mine, so I'd have to fork it).  I'm thinking that perhaps it's better for me to manually create templates for things to go into `jail.d`, but I was just trying to figure out if ansible really can't handle this pattern or if I was missing something.