# Merging shared parameters with environment specific parameter in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I run my playbooks specifying the target server environment on the command line, e.g.:

`ansible-playbook -e env=staging playbook.yml`

Now I want to be able to provide parameters, e.g. dictionary of users to create on the server in such a way that there are users **common** to all environments, and also users that are **specific** to **that one** environment for which I run the playbook.

The directory structure could look like this:

```
├── group_vars
│   ├── all
│   │   ├── users.yml
│   │  
│   ├── development
│   │   ├── users.yml
│   │  
│   ├── production
│   │   ├── users.yml
│   │  
│   └── staging
│       ├── users.yml
```

I initially thought that a setup like this would do the job. However, the `users.yml` dictionaries for each environment are never *merged* with `all/users.yml`

`ansible-playbook -e env=production playbook.yml` would just read from `production/users.yml`.

How can I have Ansible merge `users.yml` from specific environments with `all/users.yml` - so that I always have the common and env-specific users created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554415/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-separate-files-into-one-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible by default will override hash/dictionary values by their equivalents that have a higher precedence.

You can override this by change the [`hash_behaviour`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) option in ansible.cfg if you really want but I would suggest against it at such a global level.

Instead you could define your users like this:

```
users:
  name: dev-foo
  ...
```

and then also have an `all_users` variable defined in your all group_vars like this:

```
all_users:
  name: common-foo
  ...
```

And then you could [combine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the variables either by using a [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) task to create the merged variable like this:

```
name: combine users
set_fact:
  combined_users: '{{ users | combine(all_users) }}'
```

Or you could combine it directly in the task where you intend to use it:

```
name: create users
user:
  name: {{ item.name }}
  ...
with_items: '{{ users | combine(all_users) }}'
```

If you're simply trying to combine 2 lists you can do this with simple addition of the lists:

```
name: combine users
set_fact:
  combined_users: '{{ users + all_users }}'
```

Or just directly:

```
name: create users
user:
  name: {{ item.name }}
  ...
with_items: users + all_users
```