# Ansible: multiple vars_files with same yaml structure do not merge

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible playbook that uses two var files; one for general properties and others for me specific properties.  However, there are some properties from both files that share the same root YAML structure (`aws.ec2`) but when I run my playbook, it seems like the properties do not merge into one tree, but the last listed file overwrites the previous for any props using `aws.ec2`.

Playbook

```
- name: Play 1. Create AWS Environment
  hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - var_files/aws_management_vars.yml
    - var_files/aws_general_vars.yml
```

aws_management_vars.yml

```
aws:
  ec2:
    node:
      name: "Management Node"
      instance_type: "t2.micro"
      ...
```

aws_general_vars.yml

```
aws:
  region: us-west-1
  ec2:
    env: mih-env
    vpc_id: vpc-abc12345
    ...
```

When I run my playbook, if I have the vars file in the order here, it complains that it cannot find `aws.ec2.node`.

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'node'
```

If I swap the order, it complains that it cannot find `aws.region`.

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'region'
```

Is this a limitation of `vars_files` and is there something else I can use that will parse the yml files and merge properties that have the same structure?  I know I could just rename the structure in the files, but I would like it keep it this way if possible.

**Ansible v2.7.8**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554415/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-separate-files-into-one-array)

Comment: The accepted answer in this link is wrong. It says: "You can not do that.". This is not true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: ***"Is this a limitation of `vars_files?` What can I use that will parse the yml files and merge properties that have the same structure?"***

A: Yes. It's a limitation of `vars_files`. It's possible to **control how variables merge**. See [DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). But this is **not recommended**. Quoting: "*We generally recommend not using this setting unless you think you have an absolute need for it.*"

There is a simple solution. Use [`include_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task), put the included data into dictionaries, and [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) them. Set `recursive=True` to merge the keys. For example,

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: var_files/aws_management_vars.yml
        name: management
    - include_vars:
        file: var_files/aws_general_vars.yml
        name: general
    - set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ management|combine(general, recursive=True) }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_vars.aws
```

give

```yaml
  my_vars.aws:
    ec2:
      env: mih-env
      node:
        instance_type: t2.micro
        name: Management Node
      vpc_id: vpc-abc12345
    region: us-west-1
```

---

Q: ***"`include_vars` complained that it cannot be used at playbook level. Would I need to add this to the top of all tasks being run in a playbook?"***

A: Yes. `include_vars` is a task. Put it at the top of the tasks. See [Variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). `include_vars` (precedence 18.) will overwrite task's, block's and roles' vars (17,16,15).  When putting it at the top of the tasks, then there is practically no difference between `include_vars` and `vars_files` (precedence 14). As a consequence, use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) instead of [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles) if any.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBotka, I tried `include_vars` but it complained that it cannot be used at playbook level.  Would I need to add this to the top of all tasks being run in a playbook?

Comment: Great, this is working as hoped now.  Thank you for your answer, much appreciated!