# Why can't I append to a list with ansible

Tags: ansible, concatenation

I have a fairly simple requirement, I want to concatenate yaml lists from 2 or more files.

file1.yml

```
test:
  - start1
  - begin1
  - middle1
  - end1
```

file2.yml

```
test:
  - start2
  - begin2
  - middle2
  - end2
```

I want to be able to call a role, passing in all the values from all lists.

The code I have managed to work out is:

```
- name:
  set_fact:
    mytests: "{{ mytests|d([]) + (lookup('file', item)|from_yaml).test }}" # this gets the list called 'test' from current file.
  loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'test_suites/QS_suite/*.yml') }}" # loops through the files

- name:
  debug: var=mytests
```

This gives me the following output, the list mytests only ever contains the lest set of values from the last file:

```
TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/andy/PycharmProjects/mybook/playbooks/loop_test.yml:15
ok: [localhost] => (item=/home/andy/PycharmProjects/mybook/playbooks/test_suites/my_suite/1_regression_test.yml) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "mytests": [
            "start1", 
            "begin1", 
            "middle1", 
            "end1"
        ]
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "/home/andy/PycharmProjects/mybook/playbooks/test_suites/my_suite/1_regression_test.yml"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=/home/andy/PycharmProjects/mybook/playbooks/test_suites/my_suite/2_regression_test.yml) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "mytests": [
            "start2", 
            "begin2", 
            "middle2", 
            "end2"
        ]
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "/home/andy/PycharmProjects/mybook/playbooks/test_suites/my_suite/2_regression_test.yml"
}

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/andy/PycharmProjects/mybook/playbooks/loop_test.yml:20
# Only last set of values
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mytests": [
        "start2", 
        "begin2", 
        "middle2", 
        "end2"
    ]
}
```

In it's most basic form I am trying to read the files (2 of them) into a list like this:

```
- name: getfiles
  set_fact:
    myfiles: "{{myfiles|d([]) + [item] }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - 'test_suites/QS_suite/*.yml'
- name:
  debug: var=myfiles
```

This doesn't seem to want to add the 2nd file name to the list containing the first.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554415/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-separate-files-into-one-array)

Comment: Your code works for me without any modification. What callback do you use?

Comment: The with_fileglob code works with 2.12.2, I can work with this now I think. Must be a version thing!

Answer (score 0):

So looks like it's a version thing - see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/39389

My original code works with 2.12.2

I've added a sort to the query to return the file list in alphabetical order.

```
- name:
  set_fact:
    mytests: "{{ mytests|d([]) + (lookup('file', item)|from_yaml).test }}" # this gets the list called 'test' from current file.
  loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'test_suites/QS_suite/*.yml')|sort }}" # loops through the files
```