# Register a list of variables from file in ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

I have a file **/tmp/components_list** with a content like this:

```
ComponentA: '1263'
ComponentB: '989'
ComponentC: '1354'
```

I want to register variables in ansible (without quotes), according to the content of file and use them in the yml code.

So, as a result I need something like that:

```
- name: Get variables from file 
  Some actions with a file /tmp/components_list

- name: Using these variables 
  shell: docker run --name component artifactory:5100/radware/Component:{{ComponentA}}
```

So it should be a number in the variable **ComponentA**.

How can I do it by using ansible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) statement, see also [How to include vars file in a vars file with ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746077/how-to-include-vars-file-in-a-vars-file-with-ansible)